# Issue with matplotlib out of the blue

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, importerror

I am getting this issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Path.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 131, in <module>
    from matplotlib.rcsetup import defaultParams, validate_backend, cycler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\fontconfig_pattern.py", line 28, in <module>
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

I have tried so far:-

- To uninstall functools_lru_cache and install it again
- To uninstall matplotlib and install it again
- Removing the folders from site-dist and installing again

I have installed **Python and Pylint** for VS Code when it broke. It is not only related to VS Code, I cannot run the code directly from CMD either.

Comment: It seems a dependencies trouble. you should check if you have that library installed...

Comment: What is your python file called? if it is called path.py, it may cause issues...try renaming it

Comment: @JulioCamPlaz when I am trying to install it through pip it says I am already meeting the requirements and that it is installed.

Comment: @CodeCupboard the file has a different name, masked the path as it was a long windows path. But the files name is "Test.py". Which worked before the weekend.

Comment: @Rasmus Ekman Have you tried to uninstall??

Comment: @JulioCamPlaz as I wrote in the main post. Yes

Comment: Do you have to do it with matplotlib??? Have you tried with bokeh or another library?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this technique for importing the ‘lru_cache’ function:

```
try:
    from functools import lru_cache
except ImportError:
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache
```

Anyway, this is the website:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/backports.functools_lru_cache

you can do it this way too in a line command

```
pip install backports.functools_lru_cache
```

Comment: Tried these from other stackoverflow posts. But didnt help me.